# stored procedure in MYSQL with multiple row fetching is not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I created one procedure called Sample1

```
delimiter ;;
drop procedure if exists Sample1;;
CREATE PROCEDURE Sample1(IN lft1 INT,IN rgt1 INT)
BEGIN
declare emp1 VARCHAR(20);
SELECT emp into emp1 FROM personnell WHERE lft>lft1 and rgt < rgt1;
insert into emp_val values (emp1);
END;;
call Sample1(1,12);;
```

My Table Structure is like the following:

```
---------------------
emp     lft     rgt
---------------------
Albert  1   12
Bert    2   3
Chuck   4   11
Donna   5   6
Eddie   7   8
Fred    9   10 
--------------------
```

It is executing well but i can get the result

IF the executed query having only one row means its coming and inserted that value into the table called emp_val.

but The executed query having more than one row means its showing the following error

```
Error

SQL query:

call Sample1( 1, 12 )

MySQL said: Documentation
#1172 - Result consisted of more than one row
```

MY SUGGESTION

```
I have one suggestion to implementing array on it but how to use it i dont know any one help me..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your select query can return multiple rows, then you can't use an intermediate variable to store the query's results. You can, however, use the [`insert ... select ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) query format:

```
INSERT INTO emp_val SELECT emp FROM personnell WHERE lft>lft1 and rgt < rgt1;
```

which does it all in a single statement.